# How to make regular expression to detect rupay debit card

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Ru pay card start with these following number with 16 digits

1. 60
2. 6521
3. 6522

So how match this formats to get type as it's a rupay type of debit card

I have tried  with this regex

```
/^(((60)([0-9]{14}))|((6521)([0-9]{12}))|((6522)([0-9]{12})))$/
```

Comment: Have you tried anything else? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes i have tried with simple regex
/^(((60)([0-9]{14}))|((6521)([0-9]{12}))|((6522)([0-9]{12})))$/

Comment: @ArzebMansuri Can you update the question with the pattern you have tried?

Comment: Try `^6(?:0[0-9]{14}|52[12][0-9]{12})$` https://regex101.com/r/f58J1c/1

Comment: But the problem is it matches also discover cards as a rupay 
Discover cards having this regex 

/^6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}$/

Comment: @ArzebMansuri What should the difference in match be between those 2 patterns?

Comment: @ArzebMansuri This problem and the reasoning behind it must absolutely be part of your question, since range conflicts like that seem to be your reason for posting in the first place.

Comment: You could exclude matching `521` and `522` from the rupay Discover cards if those numbers are not valid there `^6(?!52[12])(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}$`  https://regex101.com/r/DobQem/1

Comment: Thank you so much @The fourth bird,


It's working fine with 

exclude (?!011) from rupay.  


And exclude (?!52[12]) from discover

Comment: Please add to answer that i will mark as correct answer
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match both ranges, you could exclude `011` from the first pattern and exclude `521` and `522` from the other pattern.

To exclude 011 for rupay cards:

```
^6(?!011)(?:0[0-9]{14}|52[12][0-9]{12})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^6` Start of string and match 6
- `(?!011)` Assert 011 not directly to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `0[0-9]{14}` Match a 0 and 14 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `52[12][0-9]{12}` Match 521 or 522 and 12 digits
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iULBQx/1)

To exclude 521 and 522 from discover cards

```
^6(?!52[12])(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^6` Start of string and match 6
- `(?!52[12])` Assert 521 or 522 not directly to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `011` Match 011
  - `|` Or
  - `5[0-9][0-9]` Match 5 and 2 times a digit 0-9
- `)` Close group
- `[0-9]{12}` Match 12 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DobQem/1)

Comment: By the way can help me out with what is use of [0-9][0-9] in regex

Comment: @ArzebMansuri I have added an explanation for both of the patterns. It means match 2 times a digit from 0-9

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it the old fashioned way?

Substr and a if will do the job just fine. And in my opinion is easier to read.

```
if(strlen($card) == 16 && 
   (substr($card, 0,2) == "60") ||
   substr($card, 0,4) == "6521") ||
   substr($card, 0,4) == "6522"))){
   echo "it's ru pay card";
}
```

Comment: Yes its possible but simply i wanted to learns that how to make these types of matching patterns via regex

Answer (score 0):

RuPay card BIN number also start with 3, 5, 6 & 8
RuPay card tieup with Discover & JCB card for International payment.
RuPay-Discover variant co-badged cards start with 6, RuPay-JCB variant co-badged cards start with 3,
Domestic RuPay card variant cards start with 5, 6 & 8.

So the Regular Expression which will satisfy the above consitions will be

```
/^(3|5|6|8)[0-9]{15}$/
```